# static class member for header files

Tags: c++

I am working on a class hierarchy where I have a base class containing a value which needs to be shared with all other derived classes in my code. I currently have this working by using a static double within a base class with pure virtual functions to set the value:

```
class base {
public:
    static double shared_value;
    virtual void set_value(double v) = 0;
    virtual double get_value() = 0;
};

class derived1 : public base {
public:
    void set_value(double v){ shared_value = v; }
    double get_value() { return shared_value; }
};

class derived2 : public base {
public:
    void set_value(double v){ shared_value = v; }
    double get_value() { return shared_value; }
};
etc...
```

The problem comes when I use header files with my code. I know I can't define a static member variable more than once, and using the headers is giving me multiple initialization errors.
I am not sure how else I can set and view this variable from any of the classes, any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What's shown in the header is the *declaration* of the variable. That declaration alone does not *define* the variable, and will never cause the error you quote. Make sure the *definition* of the variable exists in one and only one of the cpp files.

Comment: @dxiv is there no equivalent if the definition is made across many cpp files? I was hoping to spread these classes over several header and cpp files

Comment: If your compiler supports C++17 lookup [static inline variables](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-17-more-details-to-the-core-language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define `shared_value` in a source file like so:

```
double base::shared_value = 0;
```

Now any child class can access that value including editing it.

Comment: i had done that, my issue is i am defining the shared_value over several cpp files, depending which i wish to define it with. Is there no alternative way to do it? Also thanks for pointing out the typo i corrected it :).

Comment: You can’t define a static variable twice. What you can do is edit the static variable outside the class using `base::shared_value = 42` in any function

Comment: You can only define it in one and only one cpp file.